# Как разбить задачу в интеракторе

Tags: android, kotlin, архитектура

Есть репозитории

`TreeRepository` - получает список папок (вложенностей, дерево)
`ObjectsRepository` - объекты (содержимое дерева)
`ObjectTypeRepository` - описание типа объекта(ов)

1) Есть экран `SplashView`, в котором нужно все эти данные предварительно загрузить и закэшировать.
2) Есть экран `ObjectsView` в котором нужно собрать дерево используя данные из всех трех репозиториев.

Добавил интерактор ObjectsInteractor (пока просто как прокси работает, ну и объединяет данные из 3х репозиториев) и туда добавил получение джанныз из всех 3х репозиториев и получение комбинированных данных (т.е. собранное дерево с объектами).
Этот интерактор имеет методы:

```
getTree()
getObjects()
getObjectTypes()
getObjectsInTree()
```

и он используется и в `SplashView` и в `ObjectsView`

Вопрос:
Нужно делать разные интеракторы под эти 3 репозитория и объединять их где то в другом месте? Где?.. Сейчас, получается, нарушается SRP. А с другой стороны, кажется, что все нормально(одна бизнес фича, дерево объектов)..
+ подскажите источник, где хорошо(правильно) описано, что можно, а что нет по интерактору..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На эту тему можно конечно создать целый холивар, т.к. тут нет понятия правильно. Но я это вижу так.

У вас есть 3 репозитория, каждый из них отвечает за подгрузку одних типов данных. Все круто SPR не нарушается. Дальше вы хотите эи данные объеденить. Тут есть 2 пути:

- объеденять их всякий раз в месте где их получаете (где-то в  Presentation слое) и получится дублирование кода.
- второй вариант все же создать еще одну сущность которая будет ох объеденять и отдавать в Presentation слой уже готовые данные. Нарушается ли тут SPR? Думаю нет, сущность отвечает за одну конкретную фичу, она не знает о том как эти данные получаются. Пожалуй единственный нюанс может быть в том, что если к примеру вы в одном экране получаете все данные, а во  втором вы используете только часть этих данных (например вам не нужен там запрос `getTree()`. Тогда все же лучше это генерить в месте получения.

Поэтому мой ответ ваш ObjectsInteractor вполне нормальное решение.